# Why does this jQuery click event not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="studyTestContent" class="studyTestItem">
    <input type="text" class="dropInput" size="15">
    <ul class="inputDrop" style="display:none;">
        <li class="dropDownItem">Si</li>
        <li class="dropDownItem">y</li>
        <li class="dropDownItem">con</li>
        <li class="dropDownItem">el</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I have this jQuery:

```
$('.dropInput').click(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();
    var top = offset.top + height + "px";
    var right = offset.left + width + "px";

    $(this).next().show();

    $(this).next().css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'right': right,
        'top': top
    });
});
```

With this function I am attempting to show the `<ul>` when the input is clicked. Nothing happens when I click it. Any ideas why?

Edit: I just figured out what the problem was, I am inserting the html after the page loads so I need to do:

```
$('.dropInput').live('click', function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();
    var top = offset.top + height + "px";
    var right = offset.left + width + "px";

    $(this).next().show();

    $(this).next().css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'right': right,
        'top': top
    });
});
```

Comment: It works on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy6aV/); there must be something wrong somewhere else in the page.

Comment: Is the click event not firing or is there an issue with what supposed to execute upon firing?

Comment: Are you executing that JavaScript in a document ready handler?

Comment: Really? It seems OK here: http://jsfiddle.net/3SF2Z/

Comment: it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/AACzd/) maybe there is an error somewhere else. Can you post more about your code?

Comment: I just thought of something, I am inserting the html after the page loads, would that change anything?

Comment: Yes, that would change things. The event is never bound to the new HTML. Use jQuery live() to bind the event to the new HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inserting the HTML into the document after the initial, you will need to use jQuery live() to bind the event to the new element.

Comment: For future reference, live() is now deprecated.  Use on() instead:  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you wait until the document is ready with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
    $('.dropInput').click(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var height = $(this).height();
        var width = $(this).width();
        var top = offset.top + height + "px";
        var right = offset.left + width + "px";

        $(this).next().show();

        $(this).next().css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'right': right,
            'top': top
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).next(":hidden").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropInput').click(function() {
        var offset  =   $(this).offset(),
            height  =   $(this).height(),
            width   =   $(this).width(),
            top     =   offset.top + height + "px",
            right   =   offset.left + width + "px";

        $(this)
            .next('.inputDrop')
            .show()
            .css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'right': right,
                'top': top
            });
    });
});
```